# Delay the loop process in displaying the data

Tags: javascript, c#, json, object, progress-bar

I would like to delay the for loop process so that the loading of data looks like a progress bar.
In this code, the moment i click the button, it will directly display this data: 20/20 Records Rendered.
I would like to see the record start with 1/20 Records Rendered then after 3 seconds it will become 2/20 Records Rendered and so on.

Here is the code:

```
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="6" onClick="Run(this.value)">Run</button>
<script>
        function Run(value) {
            custRecordsRendered = 0;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: "/Tasks/RunSample",
                success: function (data) {
                    totalRecords = data[0].Total;
                    console.log("Total: " + data[0].Total);
                    console.log("Records: " + Object.keys(data).length);
                    for (var key in data) {
                        (function iterator() {
                            console.log("logs: "+data[key].Records);
                            setTimeout(iterator, 3000);
                        })();

                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            custRecordsRendered = data[key].Records;
                            updateProgress();
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }); 
            function updateProgress() {
                $("#completeCount").text(custRecordsRendered + "/" + totalRecords + " Records Rendered");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult RunSample()
    {
        List<object> countData = new List<object>();

        int count = 20;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            countData.Add(new { Total = count, Records = i });

        }
        return Json(countData);
    }
```

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got what you mean correctly .. this code may do the trick

```
    function Run(value) {
        custRecordsRendered = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: "/Home/RunSample",
            success: function (data) {

                totalRecords = data[0].Total;
                console.log("Total: " + data[0].Total);
                console.log("Records: " + Object.keys(data).length);
                var itemCount = 0;
                var progressInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    if (itemCount < data.length) {
                        console.log(itemCount);
                        console.log("logs: " + data[itemCount].Records);
                        custRecordsRendered = data[itemCount].Records;
                        updateProgress();
                        itemCount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        clearInterval(progressInterval);
                    }
                }, 500);

            }
        });
        function updateProgress() {
            $("#completeCount").text(custRecordsRendered + "/" + totalRecords + " Records Rendered");
        }
    }
```

in your code you are treating the setTimeout function as if it causes the Thread to sleep but actually, it does not what it does is setting a delayed asynchronous event that will be fired after the specified interval and execute the handler function, but the execution of the code which is after the setTimeout call will continue .. so setInterval will serve the purpose for you

Comment: Thanks for helping me.